# Ajax Jquery Chained Combos not working

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to run this tutorial from PHP Jquery cookbook but the First combo box is not populating with country data and it is empty!
I have 4 tables in the database and I have checked them and they are all good!
tables are: Country, States, Towns, and Towninfo

In my html I have:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <strong>Country</strong>
            <select id="countryList">
                <option value="">select</option>
            </select>
        </li>
        <li>
            <strong>State</strong>
            <select id="stateList">
                <option value="">select</option>
            </select>
        </li>
        <li>
            <strong>Town</strong>
            <select id="townList">
                <option value="">select</option>
            </select>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <p id="information"></p>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function()
        {
       $('select').change(getList);
            getList();
            function getList()
            {
                var url, target;
                var id = $(this).attr('id');
                var selectedValue = $(this).val();
                switch (id)
                {
                    case 'countryList':
                        if(selectedValue == '') return;
                        url = 'results.php?find=states&id='+ selectedValue;
                        target = 'stateList';
                    break;

                    case 'stateList':
                        if($(this).val() == '') return;
                        url = 'results.php?find=towns&id='+ selectedValue;
                        target = 'townList';
                    break;

                    case 'townList':
                        if($(this).val() == '') return;
                        url = 'results.php?find=information&id='+ selectedValue;
                        target = 'information';
                    break;

                    default:
                        url = 'results.php?find=country';
                        target = 'countryList';
                }
                $.get(
                    url,
                    { },
                    function(data)
                    {
                        $('#'+target).html(data);
                    }
                )
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

and in the php file I have:

```
 <?php
 $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'chain');
 $find = $_GET['find'];
  switch ($find)
  {
case 'country':
$query = 'SELECT id, countryName FROM country';
break;

    case 'states':
$query = 'SELECT id, stateName FROM states WHERE countryId='.$_GET['id'];
break;

    case 'towns':
$query = 'SELECT id, townName FROM towns WHERE stateId='.$_GET['id'];
break;
case 'information':
    $query = 'SELECT id, description FROM towninfo WHERE townId='.$_GET['id'] .' LIMIT 1';
break;
    }
    if ($mysqli->query($query)) 
    {
$result = $mysqli->query($query);
if($find == 'information')
{
    if($result->num_rows > 0)
    {
        $row = $result->fetch_array();
        echo $row[1];
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'No Information found';
    }
}
else
{
     ?>
    <option value="">select</option>
     <?php          
    while($row = $result->fetch_array()) 
    {
      ?>        
        <option value="<?php echo $row[0]; ?>"><?php echo $row[1]; ?>         </option>     
      <?php         
    }
}
     }
     ?>
```

According to book the first combobox must be populated after the page has been loaded but the I do not know why it is empty! can you please let me know why this is happening!

Answer (score 0):

Calling:
    getList();

after your page loaded won't work as it does not have right context of value "this".

You can try to use:

```
$('select').trigger("change");
```

instead of getList(); for first time loading

or another way to try:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('select').change(getList);
    getList.call($('select'));
    function getList(){...}
}
```

this should set the right context.(but I'm not 100% sure if it will work, as haven't tried to make fiddle.)